# Missing formatted_phone_number field in Google Places autocomplete API's getPlace Details response

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am trying to use Google places autocomplete API for one of my application.
It works allright. But, I dont get the key formatted_phone_number in the result for the place detail request.

This is what I've been trying:

Step1: Call to autocomplete api with keyword "Mike's chili" as below:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=Mike%27s%20chili&types=establishment&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyC2L1pPVbgCXUFuobrHS6vjN1RPbjibaME

Step2: Use the reference key in the first result of above request and make call to google Places Detail api as below:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?reference=CmReAAAAtR79EFJeGGLjMflCzFh_n5Rl4rEJfU_dg-zs-1ZyPVHQQmMneLO2P0J4APa3dpV2YvscqbyOK50iARnevHcUOnRvAc33hDGQQAPWxJbzSTw0GF3nDOXP1R7Zep68Yc37EhAmWbhrqVT3Ht-SffUHi1jgGhR81n4FV2ywKBkmbS8_4MrsI85w8w&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyC2L1pPVbgCXUFuobrHS6vjN1RPbjibaME

But, I dont get the field called formatted_phone_number in return. This happens for some of the other results also.
When I search for the same in Google maps, I get the phone number.

[image]

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: This is a know issue and we are working to fix this ASAP. The issue have been submitted on the issue tracker here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4016
Please click the 'star' icon to be notified of future changes.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your reply. Interestingly today when I try to replicate the same problem, I get different reference in return to my first api call and I get the formatted_phone_number key in the second call with this reference. Can you please confirm if its been fixed? Really appreciate your response.

Comment: I can confirm this has now been fixed.

Comment: @Chirs Do you have any idea about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118268/google-places-returns-wrong-city