# Google Places returns wrong city

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am building an application using google autocomplete Places API.
If I use the predictive suggestion for the address "Pongal, New York, NY, United States", I get following items in the return place object:

locality: Manhattan

administrative_area_level_2: New York

administrative_area_level_1: New York

As per documentation of google Places at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/   For US,  *locality* can be used to fetch the *city* or *town* and *administrative_area_level_1* can be used for *State*.

So, I get *New York* as *state* and *Manhattan* as *city* which is wrong since *Manhattan* is not the *city*, the *city* for this address is *New York*

May be I am asking too much from Google. But, Really appreciate any help on this since it breaks my system in later stages or Please correct me if I am doing something wrong.

Google Maps address link under the scanner: http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Pongal,+New+York,+NY,+United+States&hl=en&ll=40.748492,-73.976612&spn=0.017947,0.042014&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=38.365962,86.044922&oq=pongal&hq=Pongal,+New+York,+NY,+United+States&t=m&z=15&iwloc=A

Comment: Your assumption is right, the information about the locality is wrong. You may report this problem to google.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dr. Molie. Not sure, But Google suggests to post all queries on Stackoverflow. So, I thought someone from Google will take this question into notice.

Comment: Stackoverflow is the place to ask questions about applications that use google-maps, bugs may be reported at the issue-tracker: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list

Comment: @VishalSharma I have responded to this issue on the issue tracker here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4075

Comment: @Dr.Molle Thanks a lot for guiding to the right place.

Comment: @ChrisGreen Thanks man. Really appreciate your quick response.

Comment: @VishalSharma i recently worked on Places API, one little question, Is Locality value is always city name in any country ?? & pls help me in this problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/12024394/582571